# Ошибка в триггере

Tags: sql, firebird, триггеры-sql

Есть триггер

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER AU_CONTRACT_EXTRA FOR CONTRACT_EXTRA
ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
begin
  if (((new.EXECUTE_BEGIN <> old.EXECUTE_BEGIN)
    or (old.EXECUTE_BEGIN is null))
    or ((new.EXECUTE_END <> old.EXECUTE_END)
    or (old.EXECUTE_END is null))) then
    execute procedure SP_PROPOSAL_ADD_TO_CONTRACT(-1, old.CONTRACT_ID, 2);
end
```

который, при обновлении двух полей «*EXECUTE_BEGIN*» и «*EXECUTE_END*» вызывает процедуру, которая обновляет (по своим условиям) эти же 2 поля в этой таблице, только в других строках. При обновлении записей в этих двух полях, обновляются конкретные записи в этой таблице.
Но мне мешают строки 
`(old.EXECUTE_BEGIN is null)` и `(old.EXECUTE_END is null)` - дело в том, что при обновлении **какого-нибудь другого** поля в данной таблице, также вызывается процедура «*SP_PROPOSAL_ADD_TO_CONTRACT*» и ошибка:

> Too many concurrent executions of the same request.

Но без этих двух строк в триггере, процедура «SP_PROPOSAL_ADD_TO_CONTRACT» **НЕ** вызывается, если в полях стоит «null»

Или это **ПЛОХАЯ** идея писать треггер на обновление полей своей же таблицы?

Как поступить?

Comment: `IF (OLD.field = NEW.field) THEN (some dummy statement); ELSE EXECUTE ... ;` ?

Comment: *Или это ПЛОХАЯ идея писать треггер на обновление полей своей же таблицы?* Я бы сказал - безнадёжная. В том смысле, что корректировать вставляемые или обновляемые поля нужно в BEFORE UPDATE. А в AFTER UPDATE выполнять действия с другими объектами (записями, таблицами) - гарантируя, что само обновление текущей таблицы уже выполнено.

Comment: тогда лучше не из триггера вызывать эту процедуру, а из приложения. У меня *Delphi* и *ibDataSet*, и в нем есть "**old.value**" и "**new.value**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то условие должно быть:

```
if (((new.EXECUTE_BEGIN <> old.EXECUTE_BEGIN)
  or (old.EXECUTE_BEGIN is null and new.EXECUTE_BEGIN is not null)
  or (old.EXECUTE_BEGIN is not null and new.EXECUTE_BEGIN is null))
  or ((new.EXECUTE_END <> old.EXECUTE_END)
  or (old.EXECUTE_END is null and new.EXECUTE_END is not null)
  or (old.EXECUTE_END is not null and new.EXECUTE_END is null))) then
execute procedure SP_PROPOSAL_ADD_TO_CONTRACT(-1, old.CONTRACT_ID, 2);
```

или если у вас FB версии 2.5 и выше, то

```
if (((new.EXECUTE_BEGIN IS DISTINCT FROM old.EXECUTE_BEGIN)
  or (old.EXECUTE_END IS DISTINCT FROM new.EXECUTE_END))) then
execute procedure SP_PROPOSAL_ADD_TO_CONTRACT(-1, old.CONTRACT_ID, 2);
```

Comment: Всем Спасибо за подсказки. Работает только первый вариант, хотя у меня FB 3.0

Comment: Нашел аналогичный ответ в документации http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq133/